# Mysql query remove duplicate

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table (scheduler_history) with information/history of a resource allocation for test. Information logged include the date-time of allocation and release date-time with a cross reference key in the same table,

An allocation and release can be seen from the table by filtering on the key as below

```
select * from scheduler_history ac where ac.key = "Hp8INWFYlT"

# id, ate_unit_type, action_type, reason, created_date, modified, assigned_unit_id, key
68337, VHC25, 2, SOAK-TEST, 2023-11-01 18:56:55.415452, 2023-11-01 18:56:55.415483, 37, Hp8INWFYlT
68338, VHC25, 2, SOAK-TEST, 2023-11-01 18:56:55.415523, 2023-11-01 18:56:55.415542, 156, Hp8INWFYlT
68392, VHC25, 9, , 2023-11-02 10:00:45.371648, 2023-11-02 10:00:45.371678, 37, Hp8INWFYlT
68393, VHC25, 9, , 2023-11-02 10:00:45.371716, 2023-11-02 10:00:45.371732, 156, Hp8INWFYlT
```

where action_type column indicate the allocation action, 2 means unit allocation successful and 9 means allocated unit release

I want to extract for each allocated unit the elapsed time since it was allocated, so this will be release created_date minus allocated created date,

so having a query like this give me duplicate:

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,his.created_date, aff.created_date) as "Total Time in use(minute)", his.created_date as "Veeahub Assigned Date", aff.created_date as "Veeahub Released Date", aff.key as "Assignment Key", his.reason as "Assigned Reason"
from scheduler_history his
inner join (select ab.created_date, ab.key, ab.action_type
from scheduler_history ab
where ab.action_type = 9) aff on aff.key = his.key
where his.action_type = 2 and his.key = "Hp8INWFYlT"
```

produces duplicates

```
# Total Time in use(minute), Veeahub Assigned Date, Veeahub Released Date, Assignment Key, Assigned Reason
903, 2023-11-01 18:56:55.415452, 2023-11-02 10:00:45.371648, Hp8INWFYlT, SOAK-TEST
903, 2023-11-01 18:56:55.415523, 2023-11-02 10:00:45.371648, Hp8INWFYlT, SOAK-TEST
903, 2023-11-01 18:56:55.415452, 2023-11-02 10:00:45.371716, Hp8INWFYlT, SOAK-TEST
903, 2023-11-01 18:56:55.415523, 2023-11-02 10:00:45.371716, Hp8INWFYlT, SOAK-TEST
```

any idea why the duplicates or how to structure the code, to get what I really want
I want to have :

```
# Total Time in use(minute), Veeahub Assigned Date, Veeahub Released Date, Assignment Key, Assigned Reason
903, 2023-11-01 18:56:55.415452, 2023-11-02 10:00:45.371648, Hp8INWFYlT, SOAK-TEST
903, 2023-11-01 18:56:55.415452, 2023-11-02 10:00:45.371716, Hp8INWFYlT, SOAK-TEST
```

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,his.created_date, aff.created_date) as "Total Time in use(minute)", his.created_date as "Veeahub Assigned Date", aff.created_date as "Veeahub Released Date", aff.key as "Assignment Key", his.reason as "Assigned Reason"
from scheduler_history his
inner join (select ab.created_date, ab.key, ab.action_type
from scheduler_history ab
where ab.action_type = 9) aff on aff.key = his.key
where his.action_type = 2 and his.key = "Hp8INWFYlT"
```

Comment: MySQL is not the same thing as SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: More rows than expected for a join, implies that the join condition is not unique. So for each row in your first table, there is more than one in the second. (or sub-query in your case)

Comment: You should probably add assigned_unit_id to the join?

Comment: Thanks @siggemannen, adding assigned_unit_id to the join removed the duplicate

Answer (score -1):

to achieve data integrity add UNIQUE INDEX to the table.

OR

```sql
DELETE FROM 
  scheduler_history 
WHERE 
  id IN (
    select id 
  from 
      scheduler_history his 
      inner join (
        select 
          ab.created_date, 
          ab.key, 
          ab.action_type 
        from 
          scheduler_history ab 
        where 
          ab.action_type = 9
      ) aff on aff.key = his.key 
    where 
      his.action_type = 2 
      and his.key = "Hp8INWFYlT"
  )
```